# Transactions in database not working in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am using the following code, but experiencing some problems:

```
mDb.beginTransaction();
String updateQuery ="Query entered here"; 
String[] valVars = { Variables initialized here };
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
if (c != null)
{
    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    mDb.endTransaction();
    return true;
}
else
{ 
    mDb.endTransaction();
    return false;
}
```

When I use debug instead of running `return true`, it directly reaches return false even it is in else statement. Please tell me what is the problem and how to do this properly.

Comment: I didn't clearly get what you are trying to say here, can you be a bit more specific for me atleast.

Comment: Well amd i doing everything right? secondly when i am using debugger instead of executing return true, it runs return false. Thridly , i can't see anything stored in my database once i have run this code.

Comment: "When you running the app, it returns true. When you debugging the app, it returns false." Is it the scenario you meant here? Execution goes to "else" block because when you are debugging, Cursor c becomes NULL. Use try catch block to find whether any exception has occurred when you calling one of db transaction related menthod.

Comment: ok i am using this code Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
        mDb.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
    }catch (Exception e){
          mDb.endTransaction();
          throw e;
   }
      
      mDb.endTransaction();
 }  Now eveything working fine but when i am checking database it is not storing anything in it... Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this construction, as described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29):

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    ...
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```